# Entity Framework linq query to return sub collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table that has no foreign keys in it (and I don't have control over this unfortunately). I am trying to return an entity and it's related collection as follows:

```
from charity in context.Charities
join registration in context.Registrations on charity.RegisteredNumber equals registration.RegisteredNumber
join annualReturn in context.AnnualReturns on charity.RegisteredNumber equals annualReturn.RegisteredNumber
 select new { Charity = charity, Registration = registration, AnnualReturn = annualReturn}
```

This returns me a list of charities which has a related registration (which is correct).

However a charity has multiple `AnnualReturn` whereas this just returns a single one. Is it possible for this to be a collection inside this anonymous object?

The output I'm looking for is along the lines of:

`{ Charity = singleCharity, Registration = singleRegistration, AnnualReturns = List<AnnualReturn>}`

Thanks

Comment: Please, could you specify what is the result you are expecting? you want in the anonymous object a collection of AnnualReturn?

Comment: @octavioccl I've added my expected output

Comment: Note that you can declare Navigation Properties and ForeignKey columns in your EF model that don't exist in the database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I went that route originally but unfortunately the data is rubbish and columns that should be defined as foreign didn't always have the matching entry in the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this....

```
from ar in context.AnnualReturns
group ar by annualReturn.RegisteredNumber into annualReturn
join charity in context.Charities 
                on annualReturn.Key equals charity.RegisteredNumber
join registration in context.Registrations 
                on charity.RegisteredNumber equals registration.RegisteredNumber
select new { Charity = charity, Registration = registration, AnnualReturn = annualReturn }
```

Comment: That will return duplicate charity and registration per annual return found wouldn't it? I could potentially have more collections to add to a charity so I think Charity needs to be the root entity

Comment: No.  The `group..by` gives you one annualReturn object for each `RegisteredNumber`.  And the annualReturn object is itself a collection of all the AnnualReturns rows that share that RegisteredNumber

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the `group by` line. Would I also be able to do it if there were other collections at the same level?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
from charity in context.Charities
join registration in context.Registrations on charity.RegisteredNumber equals registration.RegisteredNumber
select new { Charity = charity, 
             Registration = registration,
             AnnualReturn = context.AnnualReturns.Where(at=>ar.RegisteredNumber==charity.RegisteredNumber)}
```